# solving a fraction without calculator

Tags: roots, pi

Can anyone explain how to get to the following solution without using a calculator:

$$\arctan(\frac{-10}{-10√3}) = \frac{π}{6}$$

?

Comment: Please try to use MathJax for your questions. See a tutorial here:https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: simplify $-10/-10\sqrt{3}$ and then think about the tangent function and the unit circle

Comment: On the crontrary, how would you use a calculator to show that $\arctan(\frac{-10}{-10\sqrt 3})\ne \frac\pi6-10^{-1000}$?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow thank you! will work through unit circle related exercises and trig in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the obvious: 10/10sqrt(3)= 1/sqrt(3). "Tangent" in a right triangle is "opposite side over near side" so we have a right triangle with legs of length 1 and sqrt(3). By the Pythagorean theorem, the hypotenuse has length c, given by $c^2= 1+  3= 4$ so c= 2.  If we put two such triangles together, along their sqrt(3) sides, we have a triangle with sides 2, 2, and, 1+ 1= 2-  an equilateral triangle.  Each angle is 180/3= 60 degrees or pi/3 radians.  The original triangle is half of that- the angle is (pi/3)/2= pi/6 radians.

Comment: Thank you so much!